# OBSOLETE - Stack Insight - Track a User's Activity Over all Stack Sites

Tags: app, javascript, website, obsolete, jquery

> ## OBSOLETE - Site is dead. And domain has been un-hosted and/or parked since 2013.

### Screenshots

[image: ScreenShot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

### About

Web application to show how all a user has been involve in the different stack sites over time.

Just enter your username on the web page and you'll see a couple of views on how your interest (asking or answering a question) and authority (the communities votes on your answers) have changed over time.

#### License

Free - do what you want with it.

#### Url

Dead: <del>https://stackinsight.com</del>

#### Platform

Modern web browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome, ...) with Flash installed.

### Contact

Feel free to post suggestions and feedback for me here.

### Code

JavaScript, [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Drastic Data Tree Map](https://www.drasticdata.nl/DDHome.php), [Google Motion Chart](https://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html)

Just 'view source' to see the JavaScript. It's all in the single stack.js file.

### Updates

- v1.0 (9th July)

  - Moved to version 1.0 of the API
  - Moved to <del>https://stackinsight.com</del> (dead link)
- v0.6 (7th July)

  - Loading of all pages of questions and answers if the user has more than 30 of each (this can be slow if you have 1000s). Suggestions welcome for how I can speed this up.
  - Prettier accounts table with loading status built in.
- v0.5 (1st July) Fixed issues when looking up more than one user without reloading the page
- v0.4 (29th June) Fixed issue picking top tags in IE and Chrome. Less 'other', more good stuff!
- v0.3 (27th June)

  - Smarter lookup of users across sites.
  - Case insensitive user lookup (thanks to farseeker for the report)
- v0.2 (26th June) - Update for API 0.9
- v0.1 (24th June) - Initial release

Comment: +1 Quite Snazzy! You may want to change the instructions - it's a little confusing. Also, when I look at the "Interest in tags by year", it only displays tags for StackApps. The other sites just display "other".

Comment: Thanks George. Which instructions do you find confusing? Only your top 30 tags over the years are reported individually. Everything else gets bundled into 'other'. I'll double this for the interest in tags by year.

Comment: @Rich: Ah - it's clear to me now. The whole thing is pretty :)

Comment: @George. Thanks. I've increased the number of tags in the treemap to 100. It looks much better now.

Comment: @Rich You should allow users to enter in User Ids instead of Names.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined /stack.js:119 - Do you still have to make some changes because of the 0.9 API?

Comment: @eWolf - Yep, it's a 0.9 issue. I'm looking into it now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @RichH is it working at the moment? I got "stack_sites is undefined" js error.

Comment: Should be fixed now with 0.9. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @RichH working good!

Comment: Competition :-O - http://stackapps.com/questions/933/stacktagz-graph-your-activity-in-tags

Comment: @RichH: Please consider listing Stack Insight on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: @George - Done. Thanks for creating a good listing site for all the apps. I'll be interested to try out the bug report feature.

Comment: @RichH: Thanks for listing your app there! Please feel free to suggest new features / things you'd like to see changed.

Comment: Here is a bug report you can look at to see what it's like: http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/view_bug.php?id=12

Comment: @RichH: The domain name no longer loads and the screenshots are not loading.

Comment: I second what George Edison said; the website is not loading.

Comment: Yeah it's Jan. 20th and the domain seems to be dead.

Comment: its still dead, jim

Comment: Site is down :-(

Comment: Is there another domain we can use?

Answer (score 3):

Is not finding me on any site: `farseeker`, main account is on SF no 7709

```
Site                    Username        Reputation    Match?
Stack Overflow          User Not Found  0             true
Server Fault            User Not Found  0             true
Super User              User Not Found  0             true
Stack Overflow Meta     User Not Found  0             true
Stack Apps              User Not Found  0             true
```

Comment: Great spot thanks. It turns out the username check is case sensitive. I'll fix that (assuming it is not the api that is the issue). In the meantine please use Farseeker.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me. I assumed it was just because I'm not very active, but it doesn't work for Jon Skeet either. This happens for me in all the browsers I've tried it with (Firefox, Opera, Arora (a webkit browser) and IE8).

Comment: Very odd. It works fine for me on IE8, Chrome and Firefox for you username. I can see JavaScript, date-explorer and discussion are you three tag with the most interest. Do you have flash installed?

Comment: I recently decided to uninstall Flash, so no. If it requires Flash, nevermind, but you might want to have it display a message if it isn't installed.

Comment: I've added info to the description above and will add a check for flash to the code soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Feature Request:

I think Stack Insight is marvelous! It is quite reminiscent of the extraordinary visualization work of [Hans Rosling](http://www.gapminder.org/).

My request is to allow the 2-step process to be a single step, i.e. I would like to bookmark my data page. Your site currently requires manually entering the user name since it is just calling a JavaScript function on the same page. Could you provide a hook so that one may bookmark it (i.e. something like `http: //www.heathtest.com/default?uname=xyz`) ?

Comment: Great idea. I'll try and add it soon.