# StackTagz - Track the topics you are interested in over time

Tags: app

### StackTagz

http://stacktagz.com

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: stacktagz]

### About

StackTagz analyses your participation in StackExchange sites by looking at which tags you are active in. A question, an answer or a comment is counted as an "interest" point in a tag. The results are rolled into weeks as this period was found to give the best overview of one's activity.

It uses a local database to cache API results fairly aggressively. Because it is assumed that once a question is out there, it's tags don't really change, it is possible to cache full timeseries and individual questions. The goal is to have the app not making a repeated call to the API ever.

### Status

Version 1.0. Future revisions will include better feedback about the progress of the graph request and turning individual timeseries on and off.

#### License

Public website, free to use.

### Contact

Contact me at izevaka@gmail.com if you have any queries or suggestions. I am planing to set up a blog and a twitter account for this site, so stay tuned.

### Code

The app is written in ASP .NET MVC2 and uses a whole bunch of awesome libraries like [Stacky](https://stackapps.com/questions/6), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/), [MS Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx), [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and a few others.

At this stage the code is closed source as it is a public website that requests makes A LOT of API calls. Once I am confident that it's fairly secure, I am planning to open source it.

Of course, I will provide source code upon request if it so happens the app is considered for the API Contest :)

**Update (2010-07-06)** User search is now performed using the api server directly, instead ofusing the stacktagz server, which in turned queried the API. Suggested users should come up much quicker now.

**Update (2010-07-08)** Fixed tooltips not being shown or shown incorrectly for some points on the graph. Added site links for user graphs.

**Update (2010-08-04)**

- Comments are now processed.
- Fixed a bug where an answer to own question will count twice towards the answer.
- Changed Rep display for 10,000-100,000 range when the decimal part is 0 - i.e. 12k instead of 12.0k.
- Changed Rep to show 'k' instead of 'K'.

#### Interesting users:

http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/22656/jon-skeet
http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/23354/marc-gravell
http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/4/joel-spolsky
http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/95810/alex-martelli
http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/18393/cletus

http://stacktagz.com/#/meta.stackoverflow.com/1/jeff-atwood
http://stacktagz.com/#/meta.stackoverflow.com/115866/balpha
http://stacktagz.com/#/meta.stackoverflow.com/811/shog9
http://stacktagz.com/#/meta.stackoverflow.com/22656/jon-skeet

Just as I am writing this and getting graphs for above users, the results are fascinating. People's interests are absolutely fascinating!!! Compare **cletus** (who is into everything) and **Alex Martelli** (die hard pythonista). Or that **shog9** is really **Jeff Atwood**'s alter ego (look at the pattern in the first year). Or that **Jon Skeet** gradually lost interest in Meta (tut tut Jon :D ).

I am thrilled to see this kind of data side by side.

Comment: +1 Nice. One thing I noticed... sometimes the little pyramid of tags on the side tends to overflow the page border. Might want to fix that.

Comment: yeah, that's a known issue, it needs a bit more love :)

Comment: Looks great Igor. It's good to have some competition. http://stackapps.com/questions/866/stack-insight-track-your-tag-usage-over-time

Comment: is this still up? I see the site not reachable